# How to show all data per cost center

Tags: mysql, sql, report, rdlc

can someone help me with my issue regarding the display of data?

SCREENSHOT A
[image: Figure A]

SCREENSHOT B
[image: Figure B]

Referring to the screenshots above, SCREENSHOT B should be displayed instead of SCREENSHOT A. Here is my query:

```
select
c.department_description,
e.cost_center_code,
sum(a.cdr_charge_amount)as total
from cdr_employees a
join employees b on a.employee_id = b.employee_id
join departments c on b.department_id = c.department_id
join employee_cost_centers d on b.employee_id = d.employee_id
join cost_centers e on d.cost_center_id = e.cost_center_id
where a.cdr_datetime > '2016-01-01 00:00:00' 
group by c.department_description, e.cost_center_code 
order by c.department_description
```

What should I do? What query should I use to display the data like SCREENSHOT B?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your query should display `B` and not `A`

Comment: At least SELECT and GROUP BY clauses look exactly as they should.

Comment: @sagi, how? It seems like it does not repeat the department name

Comment: Because you specify both `department_description, e.cost_center_code` in your GROUP BY clause. As @Serg said, the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` are as they should be

Comment: I've already followed @Serg 's instruction. But the cost center codes are just repeating but their totals are different from each other.